# Gotify and emoji

Tags: powershell, push-notification, veeam

I need a push notification on gotify for veeam backup agent, for this i made this script:

```
# Set the console output encoding to UTF-8
[Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8

Function Send-Gotify {
    Param([Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][String]$Message)
    
    $GotifyServer = "censored"
    $GotifyPort = "censored"  # Replace with your Gotify port
    $GotifyToken = "censored"
    $CustomText = "Test"

    $RequestBody = @{
        title = "$GotifyTitle $CustomText"
        message = $Message
    } | ConvertTo-Json

    [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12

    try {
        $Uri = "$GotifyServer`:$GotifyPort/message"
        Write-Host "Sending Gotify message to $Uri"
        $Response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $Uri -Method Post -Headers @{
            "X-Gotify-Key" = $GotifyToken
        } -Body $RequestBody -ContentType 'application/json'

        Write-Host "Gotify message sent successfully. Response: $($Response | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 5)"
    } catch {
        Write-Host "Failed to send Gotify message. Error: $_"
    }
}

# Get the last event with ID 190
$A = Get-WinEvent -MaxEvents 1 -FilterHashTable @{Logname = "Veeam Agent"; ID = 190}

if ($A) {
    $Message = $A.Message
    $EventTime = $A.TimeCreated

    # Format the event date (not time)
    $FormattedEventDate = $EventTime.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")

    # Check if the event message contains "Success", "Failed", or "Warning"
    if ($Message -match "Success") {
        $GotifyTitle = "[V] $CustomText"  # Checkmark ASCII code
    } elseif ($Message -match "Failed") {
        $GotifyTitle = "[X] $CustomText"  # Cross ASCII code
    } elseif ($Message -match "Warning") {
        $GotifyTitle = "[!] $CustomText"  # Warning ASCII code
    }

    # Check if the event date is equal to the current date
    if ($FormattedEventDate -eq (Get-Date).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")) {
        $EventTimeString = "Event Time: $($EventTime.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"))"

        # Check if the event is older than 10 minutes
        $TimeDifference = (Get-Date) - $EventTime
        if ($TimeDifference.TotalMinutes -gt 10) {
            exit
        }

        # Concatenate custom string, event time, and message
        $MessageToSend = "$EventTimeString`r`n$Message"

        # Send the message via Gotify
        Send-Gotify $MessageToSend
    } else {
        exit
    }
} else {
    exit
}
```

The problem are i need emoji for fast check the status of the backup but no one solution i tried works
I need red circle for fail, orange for warning, green for backup success, anyone can help me pls?

I tried html entities but not work

Comment: See following : https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Automate-Desktop/How-to-output-quot-emoji-quot-characters-in-UTF-8-from-action/td-p/1313578

Comment: In short: In _PowerShell (Core) 7.3.x and below_ as well as in _Windows PowerShell_, posting _text_ data makes PowerShell apply _ISO-8859-1_ encoding by default; to override that, either specify a `charset` attribute as part of a `-ContentType` argument (e.g. `-ContentType 'application/json; charset=utf-8'`) or pass a _byte array_ that represents the desired character encoding (such as UTF-8) to the `-Body` parameter.
In PowerShell 7.4+, _UTF-8_ is now the default.
See the linked duplicate for details.